# How do you make this ajax example work on opera and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have a quick question, the following only works on IE 7 and above, how can I make it work on firefox and opera aswell?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.tdsoft.se/index.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit**

Thanks for all your answers, now I just have another question regarding the followng code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","index.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();


}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to search through the xmlhttp.responseText (in other words call the function **loadXMLDoc()**) for key words, like for example "testfile" and if it exists multiple example "testfile_1" and "testfile_2"....."testfile_n" then **"doSomething"**

like this

```
function searchADocument(wordToSearchFor){
int numberOfTimesWordOccurs=0;
var thePageToSearchThrough [] = loadXMLDoc();
for (i=0; i<thePageToSearchThrough.length; i++){
if(thePageToSearchThrough[i]==wordToSearchFor)
 numberOfTimesWordOccurs++;
}
If  (wordToSearchFor > 1) 
document.write("<a href="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile_1">    testfile_1</a>"<a href="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile_2">    testfile_2</a><a href="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile_n">    testfile_n</a>
```

)

```
Else

window.location="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile.html";

}
```

I don't know where to start since I don't know what type xmlhttp.responseText is, can I store it in an array and scan it using for loop etc?
Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: just checked, and there are no error in the error console in firefox atleast, and as I said, it works in Internet Explorer and not in the other 2 browsers.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description of the problem you perceive; please try to formulate your issue with more details.

Comment: i have answered you but someone deleted my answer!

Comment: I don't know where you see the potential errors (the console that you are talking about). And thats random, haven't checked this site since I posted the question :/ 

Anyway, are there a firefox plugin where you can see these types of errors like you can in explorer in the bottom of the page?

Comment: just checked, and there are no error in the error console in firefox atleast, and as I said, it works in Internet Explorer and not in the other 2 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ajax("http://www.tdsoft.se/index.html", function(data) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = data;
});
```

**Code**

```
function getXmlHttpObject() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function ajax(url, onSuccess, onError) {
    var xmlHttp = getXmlHttpObject();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status != 200) {
                if (typeof onError == 'function') {
                    onError(this.responseText);
                }
            }
            else if (typeof onSuccess == 'function') {
                onSuccess(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp;
}​
```

Comment: Im sorry, that one works well in IE but dont in firefox or opera. Read somewhere that firefox has disabled this feature to make calls outside your own server, any way to get around this?

Comment: @Anders - No, only if you expect JSON. There's `window.postMessage`, but it's not widely supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage